# font-smoothing:antialiased Vs. transform:perspective(0);

Tags: html, css, safari, webkit

I'm looking at the CSS for a site I'm working on and they're using

```
-webkit-transform: perspective(0)
```

on text, which is giving it the same appearance as

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased
```

I've created an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/pxqEc/6/).

There are no transforms on the site, so I'm thinking it's purely for the better appearance.

I've never seen this hack and can't find any mentions of it online. Is there any reason why it would be used instead of font-smoothing?

Answer (score 2):

The hack they are using triggers hardware accelerated mode. This has a side-effect of changing subpixel-antialising to standard anti-aliasing.

The reason for this behavior is that sub pixel anti-aliasing makes assumptions about the background of the text. When the text is rendered onto a hardware layer, those assumptions are no longer safe, and the text is rendered with standard antialiasing to avoid potential artifacts.